# How can I split up a block of text using substr and a read more link to show the rest of it?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, substr

In wordpress a simple call is used to show the page content:

```
the_content()
```

I'm trying to develop a mobile optimised version of this, that will only show a portion of the content, with a 'Read More' link at the end, which would 'slide down' the rest of the content for the user to read.

So far, I've only been able to come up with this:

```
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 200)." <a href='#'>Read more</a>";
```

However, I'm not sure how I can get to show the rest of the content, even at all let alone sliding down.

Is there a way I can switch from substr to the full `the_content()` when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to loop through the fullc ontent dividing it into blocks.
Then you will need to display the first block.
The button should allow you to display the next block with a simple counter keeping track of the next block

CSS

```
.hidden
{
   display: none;
 }
```

PHP

```
$content = get_the_content();
///You're going to need some additional checks here for the ending sequence
for($I = 0; $I < str_len($content) / 200; $I++)
{
    echo "<div id='Content" . $I . "' class='hidden'>" . substr($I * 200, ($I + 1) * 200) . "</div>";
}
echo "<a href='#' onclick='DisplayNext();'>Read More</a>";
```

JS

```
 var I = 0;
 DisplayNext();
 function DisplayNext()
 {
 ///You should check to make sure the element exists and handle when you ge tto the last element.
 document.getElementById("Content" + I++).style.display = "block";
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting a call to undefined function len() - is that even a function?

Comment: Do you mean strlen() ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what's going on here, as none of the content is showing up when the page loads, although the read more link does.. but doesn't do anything when clicked.

Comment: Should be onclick="DisplayNext();"  And you can add DisplayNext(); in the JS to load the first block...

Comment: I don't know, nothing's showing up with the content, all i get is a read more link that goes nowhere. No JS errors or warnings or anything.

Comment: IS your content length less than 200? As I commented you're going to want to handle the end condition properly, right now it'll just cut off to the last full 200 characters.  (PHP For loop)

Comment: It's definitely not less than 200, there's about 3 or 4 paragraphs on the page i'm testing. I'm leaving it for now, coming back to it Monday. Thanks for your help